Scaffolding (DB first) does not generate Model class
Hi I tried to generate model class based on existing view. This is the command I used in PMC:
Scaffold-DbContext "//connectionstring" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -schema //schema -table //table -OutputDir Models


It seems like it is working. However it does not generate anything in my solution explorer.
I have also tried
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold

in .Net Core CLI. It did not generate anything as well. Is there anything I missed out?
Below are the dependencies in my project. I am using .NET 8.0, console app.


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#specifying-tables-and-views suggests that all views should be defined? No idea.

@JeremyLakeman Nope. It suggests that You can limit which tables and views are scaffolded by specifying schemas and tables.

"By default, all tables and views in the database schema are scaffolded ..." which is what I said.

I changed my command in PMC to
Scaffold-DbContext "//connectionstring" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -Table //schemaName.tableName -OutputDir Models

it took a while to finally generate Models folder with context class and model class in it.
